# Will my Logitech 9000 Pro webcam (still) work with Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, webcam

It USED to work - maybe around version 8.04 or earlier. Now all the video apps I used to use just tell me that they can't find a video device.

Even with xscreensavers configured to grab video images, it tells me there's no video device at /dev/video0.

Previously I didn't have to DO anything to make it work. Apparently that's changed?

Thanks in advance!

Aaron

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the Logitech **Quickcam** Pro 9000 then i can confirm it works perfectly because i have the same one ;)

The following things work perfectly:

- Microphone (Although you need to specify in the sound configuration that you want to use the Mic from the Webcam if you have another Mic connected)
- Changing Brightness, Contrast and Focus.
- Taking Pictures (With Cheese for example).
- Video Recording (If you get slow video then just point the Webcam to some BRIGHT light source then slowly point it to the place you want to record or take a picture. The webcam will auto correct itself)
- Very good lighting (Even in Dark places it does a good job, at least for a Webcam)
- You can change resolution in programs like Cheese (It has very high Resolutions but it lags a little on the higher ones.)

In my case to make it work in Ubuntu 11.04 was this:

1. Install Ubuntu 11.04
2. Connect Webcam
3. OMG IT WORKS!!

EDIT - Confirmed again i even used the Motion Tracker program **motion** and it detected my brother sloooooowly entering the room GOTCHA!!

Comment: I wish it was that easy for me. It USED to be. I can't imagine what changed. I actually was hoping to use it with **motion** actually. This is a slightly older computer (~2.8Ghz P4). If it only has USB1 ports could that cause a problem? I think the device is only USB1.

Comment: Nice, another WebCam problem. Can you provide the last lines of dmesg when you connect the webcam?

Answer (score 0):

Try running gstreamer-properties and make sure the device is selected. After that try using v4l2ucp to test.

Comment: Ok. In gstreamer-properties, under video > default input, it's set to v4l2. Device is greyed out and pressing test results in an error box that says, "Video for Linux 2 (v4l2): Cannot identify device '/dev/video0'"

V4l2ucp reports, "Unable to open file /dev/video0
No such file or directory"

FWIW, I checked the logitech page and this IS a UVC cam, which I think is more widely supported these days.

Comment: If you run lsusb is the camera listed?  Also in /dev is there a "video0" or "video"?

Comment: Nope - I don't have anything "video" in my /dev directory, and there is no camera listed when I run lsusb. Here's it's output if it helps: 

`Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5406 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro U3
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

can't format text?

Comment: Hmmm. I'll look into it some more.  Also, reply to CYREX's question below, he might have an idea.

Comment: @volvoguy Welcome to ask ubuntu, the way this site works is you need to put this information in your question, not buried in a comment. You can just click edit and add the information there.